# Spring restclient in Android Retrieving XML data via HTTP GET

Tags: android, xml, spring

all,I have a question:

TextView resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

```
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "xml"));

    HttpEntity<Doctor> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Doctor>(
            requestHeaders);
    String url = "http://192.168.1.102:8080/clinic/services/common/doctor/1";

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    ResponseEntity<Doctor> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url,
            HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Doctor.class);
    Doctor result = responseEntity.getBody();
    resultText.setText(result.toString());
```

when I run Android project throws RestClientException,follow:

org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [spring.domain.Doctor] and content type [application/xml]

How can I create a HttMessageCoonverter for xml data?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some [documentation on Spring Android regarding Rest Templates](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html).  Without seeing your Spring configuration setup, it is hard to determine the issue, but I would definitely start there.

The documentation suggests that Spring Android supports the [Simple XML Serializer](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) library by default.  Perhaps if you add that library to your classpath it will 'just work'.

Comment: Thanks for nicholas.hauschild.How can I use SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter?

Comment: Did you do as I suggested in the answer?  Get the Simple XML Serializer library and add it to your projects classpath.  I think it will just work when it is there...